# Devexpress MVC , passing object to CallbackRouteValues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, devexpress

currently I am trying to pass a whole object to the CallbackRouteValues body . I tried this

```
@Html.DevExpress.ReportViewer(
    New ReportViewerSettings With {
        .Name = Model.ReportID,
        .Report = Model.Report,
        .CallbackRouteValues = New With {.ReportID = Model.ReportID, .Model = Model, .Controller = "Sales", .Action = "GenerateSalesReceiptPartial"},
        .ExportRouteValues = New With {.Controller = "Sales", .Action = "ExportReportViewerPartial", .ReportID = Model.ReportID},
        .PrintUsingAdobePlugIn = False
    }
).GetHtml()
```

and for the controller I tried this

```
Function GenerateSalesReceiptPartial(Model As ReceiptModels.View) As ActionResult
```

where ReceiptModels.View is a class but the Model wouldn't be able to bind itself to the class , resulting empty object . Is there any other way to pass the entire object to the callback ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReportViewer uses the CallbackRouteValues value to create a callback URL. Hence, the model instance will be converted to a string.

ASP.NET MVC engine cannot parse a string and create a class instance unless it is a simple type. To make it possible, create a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) descendant, override its [CanConvertFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5th8ef6.aspx) and [ConvertFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb260h9b.aspx) methods and implement conversion from the String type to the model type. Assign this converter to the model class via the [TypeConverterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx) attribute.

UrlHelper class (it is used by the ReportVirwer to create a callback URL) do not use the type converter, though. To handle the convertation from the model to the String type, implement the [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) interface in the model class.

Comment: Yea I noticed it to work pretty as query strings , so I used Tempdata to hold complex data instead . Thanks .